# checkbox styling plugin not working

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

i am using a checkbox styling **[plugin](https://github.com/tdreyno/iphone-style-checkboxes)**  i am using two tabs inside which i have some checkbox in each tab . but the plugin is not working

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbHWs/18/)

i made a jsfiddle demo to show it the problem . even if some how it works then only when i am not using it inside any tab format . but is should nt be like this .can anyone have a look where the problem lies . ?

Comment: I would recommend using checkboxes and a label "for" the checkbox and style the label, beats using a plugin you don't understand

Comment: yes i am using this plugin for the first time . and when i use it inside tabs it dosent works properly .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey i have edited `width` with `!important` as like this

```
.iPhoneCheckContainer{
width:98px !important;
}
.iPhoneCheckHandle {
width:44px !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dbHWs/20/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the good jquery selector

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('input#on_off_on').iphoneStyle();
});​
```

=>[work](http://jsfiddle.net/dbHWs/19/) :)

---

Updated [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbHWs/20/)

Comment: friend the problem might be on doin it on jsfiddle but click on the general tab ull see what i was talkin about

Comment: General tabs? all is ok for me, what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: yes click on the general tab ull see that it dosent shows up properly (click on the tab there named "general" then u will se it dosent shows up properly

Comment: In the general tab, the button shows 1/10 of the width it should (in FF17 and Chrome 20).

Comment: yes its not working . this is what i am saying thanks @FabrícioMatté for clearing this

Comment: Hey  @SakshiSharma i have updated this Demo check to this http://jsfiddle.net/dbHWs/20/

Comment: hey @RohitAzad can u please tell me what was wrong and how u fixed i as i have to fix it on my website . please make a new answer so that i can accpet ur answer too .